# The sum of all integers less than n with a zero

Tags: algorithms

For example, if n=14, the output should be 10; n=22, the output should be 30=10+20; n=102, output=(10+...+100)+101+102=5703

In this problem, n is smaller than $10^{18}$ , and the algorithm should finish within 1 second.

Comment: Have you considered how many numbers up to $10^{18}-1$ do _not_ have the property?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon A LOT. And I would be equally thankful if you solved this problem with $n<10^6$. My proposal is to enumerate the position of the first zero(0~17) in a number and write them in the form of x0y. To calculate the sum of all y's is simple math. And what we have to do is to determine how many possible x's are there. So basically the problem above is equivalent to your question - which can be easily solved by a recursive algorithm. I'm not sure if that's valid.

Comment: My point is that since $0.9^{18} \approx 15\%$, it might be better to focus on the numbers without the property, and subtract the result from the sum of all numbers up to $n$.

Comment: May I ask what this is for? What are you applying this to? It just sounds a lot like a Google CodeJam or Project Euler problem.

Comment: @jmite you're right, this is a problem in our textbook. but there's no solution that comes with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S(m)$ be the sum of all numbers with at most $m$ digit, i.e $S(m)=10^{m+1}\cdot (10^{m+1} - 1) / 2$.

Let $C(m)$ be the number of at most m digit numbers which contains $0$.

Let $F(m)$ be the sum of numbers with zero in them such that they have at most $m$ digits.

Then is easy to find a recursive relation for $C(m)$ (hint: what is its dual?), after that you can find a recursive relation between $C(m),F(m),S(m)$ as follow:

The main problem is finding $F(m)$, but we know that, new number of m digit with zero in it, is created by number of $m-1$ digit with zero in it and padded by the numbers $0...9$, or $m-1$ digit numbers without zero padded with new zero to the end, or $m-1$ digit numbers with zero in them:

$F(m) = [F(m-1) \cdot 10 + C(m-1) \cdot 45] + (S(m-1) - F(m-1))\cdot 10 +F(m-1)\Rightarrow$

$F(m) = F(m-1)+S(m-1)\cdot 10+C(m-1)\cdot 45$

Now for calculating upto specific number, first you need to find the number of its digit, then, write it as sum of power of 10, then you can find each possible sum to each digit (from right to left).

For such a small range this works much less than a second (because is $O(\log n)$), anyway you can preprocess it.

Comment: love recursions

Answer (score 4):

Here are some hints. First, as András suggests, it is easier to sum instead all integers *without* a zero, and then use the well-known formula $1+\cdots+n = n(n+1)/2$.

Let $S_n$ be the sum of zero-less numbers up to and excluding $n$, and let $T_k$ be the sum of zero-less numbers of width *exactly* $k$. We start by calculating $S_{10^k} = T_1 + \cdots + T_k$. We have
$$ \begin{align*}
T_1 &= 1 + \cdots + 9 = 45, \\
T_2 &= 11 + \cdots + 99 = (1 + \cdots + 9 + 10 + \cdots + 90)\cdot 9 = 45 \cdot 11 \cdot 9, \\
T_3 &= 111 + \cdots + 999 = (1 + \cdots + 9 + 10 + \cdots + 90 + 100 + \cdots + 900)\cdot 81 \\ &= 45 \cdot 111 \cdot 81.
\end{align*} $$
In general we get the formula
$$ T_k = 45 \cdot (1+10+\cdots+10^{k-1}) \cdot 9^{k-1} = 5 \cdot (10^k-1) \cdot 9^{k-1}, $$
from which it is easy to compute $S_{10^k}$:
$$ S_{10^k} = \frac{5}{9} \sum_{\ell=1}^k 90^k - \frac{5}{9} \sum_{\ell=1}^k 9^k = 50 \frac{90^k-1}{89} - 5 \frac{9^k-1}{8}. $$
For the general case, let's take as an example $n = 1234$. Zero-less numbers less than $1234$ come in the following forms:

- Numbers less than $1000$: there are $1 \cdot S_{1000}$ of these.
- Numbers of the form $1XYZ$ where $X<2$: there are $1 \cdot S_{100}$ of these.
- Numbers of the form $12YZ$ where $Y<3$: there are $2 \cdot S_{10}$ of these.
- Numbers of the form $123Z$ where $Z<4$: there are $3 \cdot 1$ of these.

The general case is similar. Suppose $n = d_k \cdots d_0$, where none of the digits is zero. Then
$$ S_n = d_k S_{10^k} + (d_{k-1}-1) S_{10^{k-1}} + \cdots + (d_1-1) S_{10} + (d_0-1). $$
If one of the digits is zero, say $n = 1230456$, then we can replace $n$ with $1230000$, and use the same recipe as before, stopping at the first zero digit.